# Why did Moiraine insist that the Horn of Valere had to go to Illian?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I've read the series several times and am now going through them again after not reading them for a few years.  I just finished Eye of the world again, and noticed that Moiraine was dead set that the Horn had to be transported to Illian.

Notwithstanding the events to come wherein it never goes to Illian and things worked out in the end, I don't recall any of the prophecies saying that it needed to be in Illian, nor really any connection between the Horn and Illian except the fact that Illian would call for the Hunt periodically and that's where folks would swear their Hunters Oath.

So is there something I missed in any of the books that indicate why Moiraine would state that it needed to happen?

Comment: I'm just amazed you've read the entire series several times.  That thing is like a million pages long.

Comment: It was my absolute favorite for a while.  Still has some nostalgia for me.  For all the books after the 4th i reread all the prior books before each new release, and then I've done them 2x on audible since AMoL came out, and this is my third.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moiraine actually discusses her plans for Illian during her conference with the Amirlyn Seat in *The Great Hunt*.

> "They will travel as safely as I can manage, Siuan. And when Rand needs me in Illian, I will be there, and I will see that it is he who presents the Horn to the Council of Nine and the Assemblage. I will see to everything in Illian. Siuan, the Illianers would follow the Dragon, or Ba’alzamon himself, if he came bearing the Horn of Valere, and so will the greater part of those gathered for the Hunt. The true Dragon Reborn will not need to gather a following before nations move against him. He will begin with a nation around him and an army at his back." -- *The Great Hunt*, Chapter 5, The Shadow in Shienar

There is no prophecy beyond the Horn being needed for the Last Battle, but Illian is a nation that rallies regularly around the legend of the Horn of Valere, and in fact was calling the Great Hunt for the Horn at that very point.  Politics and scheming lords aside, this is a solid gambit by Moiraine (herself a schemer well versed in The Great Game) to put an entire nation of people on his side before he even has to deal with his enemies.

Comment: For evidence in lack of evidence, to support your answer, discussions on top WoT fansites don't really get into any extra detail about the Horn and Illian than this, either. Moiraine's motivations here seem to have satisfied the fanbase at large. "Need" was a matter of Aes Sedai wording.

Comment: Good find, I had forgotten (or not associated) the earlier statement from EotW with the one from TGH.  Much appreciated.